# Google Translator Api in Cordova

Tags: cordova, google-translate

I am using Google translator API for my website. For Mobile application in cordova is that google api supports?? It does not not works I don't know whats the problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your requirement and current implementation. :)

Comment: Sorry.. It works in cordova. I didn't add the http in link. So only it didn't work. Now it works fine. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Surya can u tell me where u added the http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try client-side translation using the JavaScript client library, the following example shows you how:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY'; // get from https://console.cloud.google.com

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function doTranslate() {
  gapi.client.language.translations.list({
      q:document.getElementById('from').value,
      target:'es'}).then(function(r) {
          document.getElementById('to').value =
              r.result.data.translations[0].translatedText; })
}
</script>
<textarea id="from"></textarea>
<textarea disable id="to"></textarea>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:api.js?onload=initGapi"></script>
<button onclick="doTranslate()">Translate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The key is the translate function which sends the translation text to the translate API using the JavaScript client library.

Answer (score 0):

They have a really easy to use RESTful API. for more details:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/getting-started#REST